# How to change label double number in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I have a problem using highchart, because i want only **normal number** (1,2,3,4 more) not **double number** (1,1,2,2,3,3 more), how to fix this ??

i already try format label in this website 
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting

Thank's

This is my screenshot

[image]

This is my code

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#chart2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Kunjungan Pasien Dan Dokter / Hari'
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
             labels: {
            format: '{value:.y:,.0f}'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Kunjungan / Hari'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} Kunjungan</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Kunjugan Pasien',
            data: [2]

        }, {
            name: 'Kunjungan Dokter',
            data: [2]

        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

Help me. Thank's  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `yAxis.tickInterval` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval)) and set it to `1` to get all numbers from 0, 1, 2...

For examle, in our code you would need:

```
yAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1
}
```

See [this updated JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/4jroh7vx/).